# Suppressing vertical space between bokeh DataTables in a column

Tags: bokeh

I have an **bokeh** application where I read various files (6 to 12) and generate **DataTable**s comparing several different variables.

So I have a loop generating **DataTable**s, adding them to a list and then finally displaying this list inside a **column**.

My problem is that the output has a big chunk of white vertical space between **DataTable**s. At first I thought it was related to the **sizing_mode** property of the layout. However, I tried *every* **sizing_mode** value possible and obtained the exact same result every time.

The actual code is too big to post here, but below I post an example notebook that ilustrates the problem (output shown below the code).

Has anyone faced the same problem? Can anyone point me to a solution?

```
%matplotlib notebook
import os
import locale
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_notebook(resources=INLINE)

l = []
for x in range(1,4):
    matriz = np.random.random((3,3))
    source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(A=matriz[:,0], 
                                          B=matriz[:,1],
                                          C=matriz[:,2]))
    columns = [TableColumn(field='A',title='A'),
              TableColumn(field='B', title='B'),
              TableColumn(field='C', title='C')]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source,columns=columns)
    l.append(data_table)
show(column(l, sizing_mode='fixed'))
```

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAupt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a height (in pixels) to `DataTable`:

```
    data_table = DataTable(source=source,columns=columns, height=120)
```

[image]

Comment: How to make the vertical distance between table 0. That is how to make tables touch each other.